# ScheduledExecutorService shutdown not working with bufferedreader?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, scheduledexecutorservice

I am using Java 8. I have a thread need start at a specific time and end at a specific time. I am using [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to do the job:

I have two threads one name is "worker" and the other is "stopworker". The `Worker` class contains the actual code I need run at the specific time, the "stopworker" thread just shuts down the scheduler.

```
 ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
 scheduler.schedule(worker, startSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 scheduler.schedule(stopWorker, endSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

My `Worker` class:

```
class Worker implements Runnable {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           try {
           // HTTP GET method to call and REST API and get Streaming
           // data back, it will keep alive as long as possible and
           // gets lots of data back
           ...
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(response.getStream()));
           // deal with the data   
           ...
           } catch (IOException e) {

           } finally {
                   reader.close();
           }
       }
}
```

My `StopWorker` class:

```
class StopWorker implements Runnable {
      @Override
      public void run() {
           try {
              scheduler.shutdownNow();
           } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
      }
}
```

My code can start at the time I want, however, it's not shutdown correctly. I have fiddle this code a little bit and found this is because the `BufferedReader` class I used.

If I replaced the "worker" thread into a simple thread sleep statement and my "stopworker" works! That's why I think I/O part might block my shutdown.

The only way I shutdown the thread is by making my `BufferedReader` variable global and close it manually in `StopWorker` class. However, the code will be ugly and an `IOException` will be throw in the code.

My guessing is the `shutdownNow` function is still waiting the I/O finish first, am I right? Is there a good way solve this elegantly? Or is there a better way to make a thread start at a specific time and end at a specific time?

Comment: Do you close you `BufferedReader reader` properly in your thread implementation? Consider wrapping it into [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block

Comment: The way to solve is to close the resource the thread is blocking on. The worker should expect to handle IOExceptions.

Comment: Yes, I have try catch finally block in my code, sorry I forgot to add it to the post, I have edit that. How do I close a thread is blocking on? where can I add that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`schedule()` returns a `ScheduledFuture`, which has a `boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)` method. If the input stream is closable by thread interruption then just call it with true.

If the stream is not interruptible then you need to close it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I have figure this out after reading all your suggestions. Thank for your help, especially for the8472.
I have changed following:
1) Change ScheduledExecutorService to ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.
For some reasons, ScheduledFuture cancel doesn't work with ScheduledExecutorService in my code and I don't know why.
2) Manually close the BufferedReader when canceling the class.

Hope this will help someone has the similar problems.